# Problem when using @@rowcount on function in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I am using `@@rowcount` in my functions like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserNameFamily] 
    (@UsrID INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Family NVARCHAR (MAX)
    DECLARE @cou INT
    
    SELECT @Name = ut.Fname, @Family = ut.Lname
    FROM User_tbl ut 
    WHERE ut.UserID = @UsrID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN 'row 0'

    IF @Name IS NULL
        SET @Name = ''

    IF @Family IS NULL  
        SET @Family = ''

    RETURN @Name + ' ' + @Family    
END
```

When I use this function in a query like that:

```
declare @ID int=3118

select * 
from Files_tbl 
where RefID = @ID    -- query rows affected is 0
    
select 
    dbo.GetUserNameFamily(TicketResponse_tbl.CreateByUserID) as CreateByFullName
from 
    TicketResponse_tbl
where 
    TicketResponse_tbl.TicketID = @ID
```

My result is:

[image: sql result]

After removing where in "select Files_tbl" query and changed this query rows affected from 0 to n.

```
declare @ID int = 3118

select * 
from Files_tbl 
-- where RefID = @ID  -- query rows affected is not 0
    
select 
    dbo.GetUserNameFamily(TicketResponse_tbl.CreateByUserID) as CreateByFullName
from 
    TicketResponse_tbl
where 
    TicketResponse_tbl.TicketID = @ID
```

My function result changes to :

[image]

This problem occurred after upgrading the database compatibility level to SQL Server 2019

Comment: What is your *exact* version of SQL Server? I would suggest you haven't updated your instance and have inlining issues.

Comment: my sql is 2019 (150) - enterprise

Comment: That's the release, I want the **exact** version. What is the output of `PRINT @@VERSION`?

Comment: when i change compatibility and downgrade that. @@rowcount work correctly

Comment: Because scalar inlining didn't exist in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
 Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 22000: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Update your instance; you are almost 3 years behind in updates, and 16 CUs behind. This was a bug that was fixed ages ago. `@@ROWCOUNT` was [omitted from inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#inlineable-scalar-udfs-requirements) in CU2; that was released on 2020-02-13. Your instance doesn't even have the GDR updates, so has known security flaws.

Comment: Separate side note; Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2019 isn't supported on  Windows 10. See [Operating System Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#operating-system-support). Considering you've forked out for Enterprise, I suggest you get that on a supported Server edition of Windows. I also suggest you get one of your DBAs to start checking for those updates more regularly. If you're paying the big money for enterprise, you can definitely afford an employee to update the host.

Comment: thanx. I update sql and solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, there [was a bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#inlineable-scalar-udfs-requirements) in the new (2019) feature called *Scalar UDF Inlining* that involved side-affecting functions such as `@@ROWCOUNT`. Updating to the latest build of SQL Server (which you should do anyway) would have fixed this.

---

Be that as it may, to continue using Inlining you can avoid `@@ROWCOUNT` by simplifying your function like this

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserNameFamily] 
    (@UsrID INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ISNULL((
        SELECT CONCAT(ut.Fname, ' ', ut.Lname)
        FROM User_tbl ut 
        WHERE ut.UserID = @UsrID
    ), 'row 0');
END
```

---

But I would advise you to just transform this into an inline Table Valued Function, which will always be inlined:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserNameFamily] 
    (@UsrID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  ISNULL((
        SELECT CONCAT(ut.Fname, ' ', ut.Lname)
        FROM User_tbl ut 
        WHERE ut.UserID = @UsrID
    ), 'row 0') AS UserName;
```

You use it like this

```sql
SELECT n.UserName
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetUserNameFamily(t.Id) n;
```